# method returning empty byte[] instead of MAC Address

Tags: c#, .net

I have following simple (trivial) method in `C#`, which should return [MAC Address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address) of selected `network interface card (NIC)`:

```
public byte[] GetMacAddress(int adapterIndex)
{
    NetworkInterface[] networkInterfaces = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();

    if ((adapterIndex >= networkInterfaces.Length) || (adapterIndex < 0))
    {
        return new byte[6] { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };
    }
    else
    {
        return networkInterfaces[adapterIndex].GetPhysicalAddress().GetAddressBytes();
    }   // if
}   // GetMacAddress
```

Now, method is called from `Program.cs` (it's `main` method):

```
using System;
using Comms.NwStack.IpLayer.IpGateway.Ndis;

namespace NDISTester
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TCP_AdapterList networkAdapters = new TCP_AdapterList();

            Console.WriteLine(networkAdapters.GetName(0) +
                              " " +
                              networkAdapters.GetMacAddress(0).ToString());
            Console.ReadKey();
        }   // Main
    }   // class
}   // namespace
```

and here is the output:

```
Local Area Connection  System.Byte[]
```

Why do I get empty `MAC Address`?

Comment: Every class in NET derives from the base class _object_ who defines the ToString method. But the ToString method of the base class object cannot be accurate for every class. So if a class needs a precise ToString implementation it should override ToString with a specific implementation. If the class doesn't override ToString() then the base ToString will simply return the name of the class. The _byte[]_ array has no override for ToString.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Byte array `ToString` method returns class name instead of it's data. `BitConverter.ToString()` to get `byte[]` data into string.

Use

```
BitConverter.ToString(networkAdapters.GetMacAddress(0));
```

instead of

```
networkAdapters.GetMacAddress(0).ToString()
```